# replace any in txt file excipt range of letters

Tags: sed, replace, tr

Please I have a txt file, I want to replace anything to `_` except this range of letters `[\0600-\06FF]`.

like

```
sed 's/^[\0600-\06FF]/_/g' < a. txt > b. txt
```

not work with me.

Comment: can u share the input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is encoded in UTF-8 and your system has a C.UTF-8 locale and your shell supports zsh's `$'\uXXXX'` operator, to replace every characters whose Unicode codepoint is outside the 0x600 - 0x6ff range with `_`, you can do:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
tr -c $'\u600-\u6ff' '[_*]' < a.txt > b.txt
```

However, it won't work with a few `tr` implementations including GNU's or busybox' that don't support multi-byte characters. You may have more luck with:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
sed $'s/[^\u600-\u6ff]/_/g' < a.txt > b.txt
```

Though it won't replace newline characters (you could pipe to `tr '\n' _` for that).

Or you could use `perl`:

```
perl -C -pe 's/[^\x{600}-\x{6ff}]/_/g' < a.txt > b.txt
```